# Create common scrolls for two iframes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

What i want to create is two scroll bars , one vertical and the horizontal and when i scroll anyone of them, both docs will scroll at the same time.

I though of giving the "divMain" "overflow:auto" property and overflow:hidden to rest of the other controls. But when i run there are scrollbars for the iframe. The scrollbar belongs to a div inside the iframe having a id xxxx.

i don't know where the div came from. May be the its with in the doc that i am showing which is an infopath report.

I gave the parent div maxheight ( which i dnt thnk is nice due to resolution issue) , now scroll came for height.

Now i want the child control (iframe) content to get scrolled as i scroll the main div scroll

**HTML:**

```
<div id="divMain">
    <div id="divChildOne" style="float: left; width: 50%;">
        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lableOne" Font-Bold="true"></asp:Label>
        <br />
        <iframe id="iFrameOne" runat="server" style="width:100%;" />
    </div>
    <div id="divChildTwo" style="float: right; width: 50%;">
        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="labelTwo" Font-Bold="true"></asp:Label>
        <br />
        <iframe id="iFrameTwo" runat="server" style="width:100%;" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks

Comment: do you have access to - ie can you alter - the iframes' sources? are they hosted on the same domain as the page in question?

Comment: Actually its a sharepoint server and the data that is binded to iframe is an infopath report.i am using the FrameServer.aspx , which is a built in viewer of Infopath files , according to my knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <div id="FieldCustom" runat="server" style="width:450px; height:400px; overflow:scroll;">

                <div id="divMain">
    <div id="divChildOne" style="float: left; width: 50%;">
        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lableOne" Font-Bold="true"></asp:Label>
        <br />
        <iframe id="iFrameOne" runat="server" style="width:100%;" />
    </div>
    <div id="divChildTwo" style="float: right; width: 50%;">
        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="labelTwo" Font-Bold="true"></asp:Label>
        <br />
        <iframe id="iFrameTwo" runat="server" style="width:100%;" />
    </div>
</div>



                </div>
```

Comment: @user3851706 Did this help u?

Comment: But is it a good practice of giving the height and width in pixels?

Comment: Yes u can give it in pixels or percentage.